# Fan is loud and the pc wont work

Tags: boot, motherboard, hardware-failure, fan, desktop-computer

this is somthing that happens to me every few months with my pc, I turned it on today and the fan started spinning loudly and the pc shlwed the dell sign on my monitor for a second then shut off but the pc was still on and still loud, Last time it happened it gave an error code with beeps but this time there were no beeps and now its just looping the boot sequence, when I have the power connected it turns on and the fan spins lout waits 5 seconds turns off and starts again
How do I fix this? Im a little worried it may not be the ram and might be to do with my motherboard but there isnt any bulged capacitors

Comment: I can provide pictures if necessary

Comment: This is way too broad. Provide everything you can as well as the steps you have gone through trying to fix it.

Comment: Does it have any flash indicators?

Comment: It doesnt have any flash indicators and I have tried to clean the ram and reolace it in a different slot